# Manually putting together parts of a date

Tags: c#

Ok, I'm not quite sure how to go about this.  Here's the scenario.

**1)** On a web form we have 3 dropdowns:  Month, Day, and Year

**2)** Year is always optional (not required)

**3)** If the customer enters month and day, and not year, we want to default the year to 1900

**4)** If the customer does enter all 3, I need to piece together a DateTime to represent that.  Either way, the year is going to have something...either a valid year or 1900 if the user did not select year.

So in my code-behind, I'm not quite sure how to set all this up.  Ultimately I need to form that date so I can update the SQL 2008 Date datatype once I send down the date to my DL update function.

So I created a DataTime variable in my code-behind method that picks up the values that the user has selected in each dropdown.  However I guess there's no setter on DateTime.Year and so fourth.  So I can't just do DateTime.year = "1900" or something to that effect.

Comment: I forgot to add that the birthday itself is optional.  That is, if they don't enter any of the 3 fields, then I need to fill the DateTime with year 1900 but what about the month and day?  what sort of default value could I put in there for SQL Server to hold?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right that there is no setter but these can all be set in the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x.aspx). You might do something like

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(year.HasValue ? year.Value : 1900, month, day)
```

Where year is an Int32?

Comment: I think you need to change that to `year.HasValue ? year.Value : 1900`, since year.Value returns an `int` and you can't perform a `null` check on an integer (`year.Value ??`).

Comment: how would I default the date to year 1990 but nothing for the day and month...well, not nothing, something has to be there but the user is not required to enter any of this birth date.  If that's the case then I need to give SQL something...a fake date with 1900 as the year.

Answer (score 4):

1. read all three pieces of information (year, month, day) from the web page into INT variables
2. replace "Year" with 1900 if empty
3. create new datetime:

   ```
   DateTime myDate = new DateTime(year, month, day)
   ```

That's about all there is, I think.

Answer (score 0):

There's a DateTime constructor that takes a year, month and a day as it's input parameters.  You can use that and put in the values from your dropdowns (defaulting to 1900 if no year is selected).

Answer (score 0):

It is also in fact possible to change the year of a `DateTime` after constructing it, though it is somewhat more laborious:

```
int yearsSinceNineteenHundred = date.Year - 1900;
date = date.AddYears(-yearsSinceNineteenHundred);
```

Answer (score -2):

Concatenate as a string and then convert to a date time.

Comment: **bad bad bad** idea!! Do you handle all different international date formats properly? Will your app doing this work in e.g. France? Japan?

Comment: Agreed it's NOT the way to go... not necessary at all and error-prone

Comment: Really, how much internation work have you done?
(a) We were not talking about internationalisation of work
(b) What's wrong with ToDateTime(String, IFormatProvider)
Which (from MSDN) Converts the specified string representation of a number to an equivalent date and time, using the specified culture-specific formatting information.

Comment: Why would you convert to a string, then parse the string according to a specific culture when you already know what is the day, month and year? Just passing the parameters to a DateTime constructor will work perfectly, will be processed faster and will be less error prone. Also, it's only one line of code.

Comment: Meta-Knight - I'm not saying it's the best way, indeed @marc_s has the best answer (which I voted for).... However, my suggestion did work and was correct, and didn't really warrant a down vote. To say "This answer is not useful" is wrong IMO.

Comment: Sorry I've got to downvote this one too.  This really isn't a "correct" answer because of the obvious issues in string parsing.  Using the DateTime constructor is clearly the correct answer here.